# Make Windows mouse feel like Mac

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse

I have built myself a PC tower running Windows 10 after being a lifelong Mac user. The mouse cursor just doesn't feel the same between the two, to me it feels a lot slower and choppier on Windows.
I've seen lots of posts about how to make a Mac mouse feel like Windows (presumably from people switching to Mac), but nothing on how to go the other way around. Does anybody have any ideas?

Clarification: It isn't about the speed of moving the pointer. It's like the draw rate of the cursor is lower than on mac. If I move the mouse past a certain speed the cursor seems to jump positions instead of moving smoothly. It isn't, or shouldn't be, an issue of hardware, as this computer has much higher specifications than - say - my MacBook Pro I use at work.

EDIT: I've identified the problem as being my monitor's refresh rate, not Windows itself. I have a Dell P2415Q 4K monitor and an Nvidia GeForce 960. It's currently pushing 4K at 30hz, and will not give me an option to go higher. When I choose a lower resolution and 60hz the mouse feels smooth as butter. I believe my graphics card should be able to drive 4k @ 60hz but I'm not sure, I'll have to investigate and see if I can force it to

Comment: This question is subjective. What you "feel" may not be the same as someone else. Can you define "choppy"? Please be specific about what you are wanting to change.

Comment: I will try to clarify what I mean when I get home this evening

Comment: If it's not giving you the 60hz option may be a driver update will do. If it doesn't do it, then it's possible that your graphic card is not capable of it, and you'll have to get a better one

Answer (score 1):

Updating my GeForce GTX 960's "game ready driver" to the latest version made the 4K @ 60hz option appear in the Nvidia control panel and all of the choppiness I was experiencing is gone. It's like a brand new computer!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to make the mouse move faster, then you might want to get in the Control Panel > Mouse then take a look in every single tabs. In the first one, there is a Speed Option. Set it as you wish.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of how to make a Windows mouse feel like a Mac mouse. You can ask clarifying questions in the comments below the question.

Comment: I cannot comment as I do not have 50 reputations.

Comment: Understood. It will come about soon. Just be careful using the answer area improperly. Comments in the answer area, or low quality answers, can actually cause you to get down votes. Down votes will make it harder to build your reputation. I will as the OP for clarification in the comments.